# Is it possible to have MASTER_DELAY on an Amazon RDS slave?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, replication, amazon-rds

I want to set "MASTER_DELAY=86400" on an Amazon RDS slave  (so my slave is 1 day behind my master).

I know how to do this in a regular master/slave setup.  I can't see that it is possible in RDS.  Am I missing something?

Comment: did you ever find the answer to this?

Comment: refer here: https://mydbops.wordpress.com/2018/11/14/delayed-replication-with-amazon-rds/